# Difference between Matcher.only() and Matcher.identicalTo() in Google Guice

Tags: guice, matcher

What's the difference between *Matcher.only()* and *Matcher.identicalTo()* in Google Guice? It seems they are the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Matchers.only(x)` matches objects where `x.equals(y)`, i.e. value equality.  `Matchers.identicalTo(x)` matches objects where `x == y`, i.e. reference equality.